# Mouse press event on QGraphicsScene::addWidget()

Tags: c++, qt, events

I have a problem with `QMenu`, which emits `aboutToHide()` every time I call `QGraphicsScene::addWidget()`. In stack i can see mouse event generated after `addWidget()`, but I can't figure out where it's generated.

```
//Window constructor:
...
QTimer* timer = new QTimer;
timer->setInterval(500);
QGLFormat fmt;
fmt.setSampleBuffers(true);
fmt.setSamples(2);
ui->graphicsView->setViewport(new QGLWidget(fmt, this));
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(addLabel()));
...
Window::addLabel()
{
   QLabel* label = new QLabel("LABEL");
   QGraphicsProxyWidget* proxy = ui->graphicsView->scene()->addWidget(label);
}
```

And then I get a menu that closes every half a second.

Comment: You are adding a label every half a second (everytime the QTimer times out). Maybe you forgot to disconnect the timer?

Comment: I'ts just an example, my question is why I get a mouse press event every time I call `addWidget()` and how to fix it.

Comment: Well, the `addWidget()` shouldn't emit any mouse press event. Can you add the rest of your code?

Comment: `addWidget()` doesn't emit a mouse press event, but the behavior of `QMenu` looks like it's emits somewhere and now I can see `QMenu::hideEvent()` in the stack. This is all the code. Simple `MainWindow` created in Designer.